# Testing Kendo Grid command

Tags: javascript, testing, kendo-ui, karma-runner

I have a KendoUI Grid with one of the columns being a command.

```
$("#table").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        command: { text: $scope.open, click: $scope.openItem},
        title: $scope.link,
        field: "Id
    }]
```

The command is bound to an angularJS scope function that looks like this

```
$scope.openItem= function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var row = $(e.currentTarget).closest("tr");

    var dataItem = this.dataItem(row);

    var id = dataItem.Id;
    var evalId = dataItem.EvaluationId;

    performeAction(id, evalId);
};
```

We are using karma to do our testing and I hit a roadblock with this 'openItem' function.

This is how the test looks at the moment

```
it("Button testing", inject(function ($compile){
     var object = {};
     element = angular.element('<myAngularDirective></myAngularDirective>');
     $compile(element)(scope);
     scope.$digest();

     //element.scope().openSelectedInstantCoach(object);
}));
```

The part that's causing problems is the commented line. The three lines above work fine for the other tests. I don't really know what I need to pass into the function because of the way kendoUI handles the click.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to simulate how Kendo UI handles "click" on commands? Maybe it is easier simulating the click and let Kendo UI generate the parameters.

Example: `grid` is the KendoUI Grid object initialized as:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ...,
    columns   : [
        { command : { text: "open", click: myClick }, title: "Cmd" },
        ...
    ]

}).data("kendoGrid");
```

When you want to click the `open` command in row `0`, you can do it as:

```
var btn = $("tr:nth(0) .k-grid-open", grid.tbody);
btn.trigger("click");
```

I'm finding the row using `tr:nth(0)` and the target `button` in the specific row using `k-grid-open` CSS class (this is something that KendoUI generates from the `text` of your button).

Now, triggering the button is as simple as invoking `trigger("click")`.

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5APDW/